# Parametrisation of a general quadratic surface?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, quadratics, surfaces, parametrization

Consider a general quadratic surface in implicit form:

\begin{equation}
ax^2 + by^2 + cz^2 + 2exy + 2fyz + 2gxz + 2lx + 2my + 2nz + d = 0
\end{equation}

I can parametrise this in the form $f(x, y, z(x,y))$ but this involves solving a quadratic and is not pretty. Is there a better parametrisation that avoids the double solution $z_{+/-}$?

Comment: One approach: non-degenerate quadrics divide into two classes of projectively equivalent surfaces—ruled and non-ruled. The non-ruled quadrics are projectively equivalent to the unit sphere, which induces a parameterization. The ruled quadrics are naturally parameterized via their rulings.

Comment: coderella, how would you parametrize the curve $$ 5 x^2 + 24 xy - 2 y^2 = 27 \; ? $$